# Example of hash collision (printable strings)

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5

I've searched a lot for MD5 hash collision, but I've found binary examples only. I would like to find two UTF-8 strings, which have the same MD5 hash. Are there any, or does the collision only work for binary data?

Comment: There surely are, whether you would want to spent the time finding them is a different question. You should just take into account that 2**128 is a quiet large number. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1999824/3194340

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412595).

Comment: There's a whole question about this on [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value) which is a much more appropriate location for this kind of question.

Comment: @Martin The answers provide binary examples only, not real UTF8 strings

Comment: @IterAtor The point being not that the question was a duplicate, but rather that it belongs on that site instead of this one

Comment: @IterAtor still not a programming question. Did you try to write code to convert that binary data to UTF8 strings? If you did and have problems making that work, then you should write a new question with that code so we can help.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412697/16886597), a second time

Answer (score 15):

It's definitely possible:

- We all agree there are collisions for MD5 due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - we are mapping infinitely many possible inputs to elements belonging to a finite sequence.
- There is a solid chance that there are infinitely many collisions: we are able to produce infinite pairs of input and MD5 tries to map them uniformly.

By that alone some of these collisions are *bound* to be valid UTF-8 strings, but they're extremely rare, since most of these will be just random binary garbage.

If you absolutely **need** to find such messages, I recommend using [collision finder written by Patrick Stach](http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/41548/md5coll.c.html), which should return pair of arbitrary messages within a few hours, or [my attempt to improve it](https://github.com/rr-/master-thesis/tree/master/proj/md5). The latter uses techniques presented in later papers by Wang (the first person to *demonstrate* examples of MD5 collisions), Lian, Sasaki, Yajima and Klima.

I think you could also use [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) to some extent, but it requires deeper understanding of what happens inside MD5.

Comment: Is it really the "birthday paradox"? I think it should be the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) (which is also linked from the birthday paradox wiki page).

Answer (score 9):

There **are** UTF-8 collisions.  By the nature of cryptographic hashes, finding them is intentionally difficult, even for a hash as broken as MD5.

You might search for MD5 Rainbow Tables, which can be used for password cracking, and hence for UTF-8 strings.  As @alk pointed out, a brute force search is going to take a very long time.

Comment: Whoever is bumping up the score for this answer, please don't.  It is old, and deserves to be left in peace.

Answer (score -5):

The canonical example of an MD5 hash collision ([hex - from here](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/)):

#### Message 1:

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70
```

#### Message 2

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70
```

are, in fact, valid UTF-8 strings. They do not contain any `NULL` bytes and are therefore UTF-8 strings. Now, they are meaningless and look like garbage when decoded:

#### Message 1:

```
1i=\/ʵF~@X>U4 䈃%qAZQ%ɟ7<[؂>1V4[m6Sⴇ9cH͠3BW~Tp
Ƙ!e+o*p
```

(some characters were control characters)

#### Message 2:

```
1i=\/ʵF~@X>U4    䈃%AZQ%ɟr7<[؂>1V4[m6S49cH͠3BW~Tp(
Ƙ!eo*p
```

(same situation)

---

Oh, and before I forget, here's the MD5 hash:

```
79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4
```

Comment: I don't believe that site will accept hex encoded data. And the UTF string isn't exactly perfectly printable. Try doing it using `xxd` and `md5sum` in a *nix shell terminal pipeline.

Comment: These are obviously not valid UTF-8. I assume your UTF-8 decoder accepts invalid byte sequences. `31 dd 02` can't be valid, since UTF-8 will never produce a single byte with the high bit set surrounded by bytes with the high bit unset.