# Generating Two Files with the Same MD5 Hash

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, md5sum

Hi I have two pdf files along with md5sums. now I want to do collision attack such that

1. Only one of the two files can be modified by the attacker. In this case, it is assumed that the attacker only has access to one PDF file, is free to edit the image whatever they choose, and that the (visible) text of the PDF should not be altered. The other PDF file, however, is completely unmodifiable by the enemy. Only the attacker is capable of reading and running the second PDF file. So, he is aware of its MD5 checksum.
2. Both files can be altered by the attacker. When an attacker submits a created program for security auditing before receiving a certificate or permission to distribute the software, this scenario frequently occurs with binary executable files. As a result, the adversary can get past the audit and then switch the application over to a malicious version. In this case, the attacker is free to alter both files' binary in order to obtain the desired MD5 checksum. The (visible) content of both files shouldn't be changed, though.

I did alot of search but nothing. anyone can help to share something

Comment: _In cryptography_ your #1 is a second-preimage attack, and only #2 is a collision attack. There are lots of resources on MD5 collisions, most of them many years old now, but no one (at least not in the open world) has a feasible second-preimage attack on MD5. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933497/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999824 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29225 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 . But this is not programming or development.